# Get preview of uploaded pdf file as image on click side

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'd like to show a preview of a PDF file before uploading. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You're new here, so I suggest posting some information about the technologies you're using, maybe some sample code showing what you've tried, and actually asking a question.

Comment: What size should the preview have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible for two reasons:

Firstly - a "pdf preview" is not something that can be handled by JavaScript.

Secondly - even if you were uploading an image, the website does not have permission to work with client side images.

---

To achieve what you are envisioning there are several solutions:

1. Upload the PDF file, then preview, and ask the user to "commit" -- this does not solve the upload time wait issue.
2. Use something like Java applet, or Flash to build a "preview and upload" applet.

Good Luck

Comment: This is not impossible, you could have a temporal folder on the server that is used exclusively to show previews and move to another location upon the user's approval.

Comment: +1 this is entirely correct. There is no way to generate a PDF preview  before uploading, using pure JavaScript. You can also not link to the local PDF file in an iframe - it will be blocked for security reasons.

Comment: you are right, removed the - 1

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to use some server-side component to generate an image of the PDF and return the image data or URL of the image back to the client so it can be set as the src of an `<img>` tag.

It's not simple, and it can't be done in JavaScript (unless there is already some JSONP-based API available from a site that can do this for you).